# Cannot access any endpoint apart from localhost in Python FastAPI

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am learning to use FastAPI on Windows.
The problem is that I cannot access any endpoint rather than localhost (`"/"`).

I have written the following code in `main.py` file that is located inside `app` folder (`app` folder contains `__init__.py` file and `main.py` file):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

my_posts = { 1:{
        "date":"01/01/2022",
        "user":"Matt",
        "type":"photo"
}
}

@app.get("/")
def get_root():
    return{"Hello":"User"} #works fine


@app.get("/post/{post_id}")
def get_post(post_id:int):
    return{"data": my_posts} #doesn't work
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, try using `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1`:

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer as the solution, so others may find it as well :) Good day!